# sql * loader file not axtracting (DATE DATATYPE)

Tags: oracle, date, sqldatatypes, sql-loader

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE "C:\\Users\\lenovo T480\\Desktop\\all_2012.csv"
DISCARDFILE "C:\\Users\\lenovo T480\\Desktop\\BANKING_DATA_DISCARDED.txt"
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE BANKDTLS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""'
(year,BACH,ACODE,XNUM,BANK,location,AREA,HEAD_NAME,
CODETX,BALANCE,COL_PIVOT,CONSOLD,DEPTNO,DEBIT,STATUS,
SUB_ADDR,PROVINCE,CONTRY,COLNO1,COLNO2,CREDIT,ADD_STATUS,
DATE1,
DATE2,
INTEREST,TAX,GENDER,STATES,STATE_CODE,type,TYPE_CODE,LOAN_CODE,LOAN_TYPE)
```

3 ROWS SAMPLE OF CSV FILE

```
2012,19048,152,286690,compass_bank,3805_a1a_south,saint_augustine,st_johns,fl,32080,brcenm,consold,11,33_317,0,los_angeles_long_beach_glendale_ca,saint_augustine_2,united_states,109,300,27260,1,9_17_97,6_30_86,29_826612,81_272145,m,florida,12,mult,1391237,4,commercial_lending,banco_bilbao_vizcaya_argentaria_s_a,bilbao,al,697633,0_5,15_south_20th_street,birmingham,al_2,35233,65_982_103,sm,call,state,state_agency,state_2,13,united_states_2,0_6,48_097_626,48_313_018,10256,escrow,5,atlanta,6,atlanta_2,dif,cb,insbrdd,insbrts,5_2,southwest_district,fed,1073,alabama,1_2
2012,19048,660,257606,Compass Bank,3809 East 42nd Street,Odessa,Ector,TX,79762,M,,11,28063,FALSE,Chicago-Naperville-Arlington Heights IL,Odessa,United States,135,372,36220,TRUE,3/13/2008,1/4/1993,31.891448,-102.343769,M,Texas,48,MULT,1391237,4,COMMERCIAL LENDING,BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A.,BILBAO,AL,697633,FALSE,15 South 20th Street,Birmingham,AL,35233,65982103,SM,CALL,STATE,State Agency,STATE,13,United States,FALSE,48097626,48313018,10256,,5,Atlanta,6,Atlanta,DIF,CB,,,5,Southwest District,FED,1073,ALABAMA,TRUE
2012,19048,620,196395,Compass Bank,3810 Hwy 365,Port Arthur,Jefferson,TX,77642,C,956,23,0,FALSE,,Port Arthur,United States,245,0,13140,TRUE,3/13/2008,3/8/1993,29.915512,-93.877536,M,Texas,48,MULT,1391237,4,COMMERCIAL LENDING,BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A.,BILBAO,AL,697633,FALSE,15 South 20th Street,Birmingham,AL,35233,65982103,SM,CALL,STATE,State Agency,STATE,13,United States,FALSE,48097626,48313018,10256,,5,Atlanta,6,Atlanta,DIF,CB,,,5,Southwest District,FED,1073,ALABAMA,TRUE
```

```
--TABLE
Create table BANKDTLS
( year number(4),BACH number(25),ACODE number(30),XNUM number(26),
  BANK varchar2(70),location varchar2(70),AREA varchar2(50),HEAD_NAME varchar2(40),
  CODETX varchar(30),BALANCE varchar(20),COL_PIVOT varchar(25),CONSOLD varchar(20),
  DEPTNO varchar(30),DEBIT varchar(30),STATUS varchar(10), SUB_ADDR varchar2(50),
  PROVINCE   varchar2(50),CONTRY varchar2(50), COLNO1 varchar(40), COLNO2 varchar(40),
  CREDIT varchar(38),ADD_STATUS varchar2(46),
  DATE1 DATE,
  DATE2 DATE,
  INTEREST varchar2(30), TAX varchar(25), GENDER varchar(30), STATES varchar2(30),
  STATE_CODE varchar(30),type varchar2(36),TYPE_CODE varchar(30),
  LOAN_CODE varchar(35), LOAN_TYPE varchar2(50)
 );
```

```
--columns(date1,date2)
--TABLE AND COLUMNS CREATED IN ORACLE WITH DATE DATATYPE
--DATE FORMAT IN FLAT FILE (9/31/2012)

--/*value used for ROWS parameter changed from 250 to 123
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table BANKDTLS, column DATE1.
ORA-01843: not a valid month

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table BANKDTLS, column DATE1.
ORA-01843: not a valid month

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table BANKDTLS, column DATE1.
ORA-01843: not a valid month*/
```

*HOW TO INSERT STRING DATA INTO DATE (DATATYPE) COLUMN USING SQL*LOADER
AND ALREADY TABLE CREATED WITH DATE(DATATYPE)*

Comment: You should also provide a sample line of your CSV file

Comment: HERE IS THE SAMPLE CSV FILE

Comment: I don't see any.

Comment: 3 ROWS SAMPLE OF CSV FILE check it now

Comment: The columns in question have values `9_17_97,6_30_86`, this does not match any `DATE` format.

Comment: THE FIRST LINE IS LOOK LIKE THE HEADER CHECK 2ND LINE AS 3/13/2008,1/4/1993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the source field datatype, SQL*Loader reads everything as CHAR(255). It doesn't know how to stick a CHAR value into a DATE column unless the format just happens to match the database's (or session's) NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. Programmers should never rely on that. Instead, they should always specify the date format their data is in. For SQL*Loader control files, you can do that in the field definition. For example:

```
. . .
(year,BACH,ACODE,XNUM,BANK,location,AREA,HEAD_NAME,
CODETX,BALANCE,COL_PIVOT,CONSOLD,DEPTNO,DEBIT,STATUS,
SUB_ADDR,PROVINCE,CONTRY,COLNO1,COLNO2,CREDIT,ADD_STATUS,
DATE1 DATE "YYYYMMHH24MISS",
DATE2 DATE "YYYYMMHH24MISS",
INTEREST,TAX,GENDER,STATES,STATE_CODE,type,TYPE_CODE,LOAN_CODE,LOAN_TYPE)
```

Change that to whatever format your date strings are in, and it should parse it correctly and then will be loading a date into a date.

Comment: "YYYYMMHH24MISS"  I THINK IN THIS 'DD' IS MISSING?       RIGHT      IS IT NECESSARY TO MENTION '24'

Comment: you are right, you'll wnat to add DD somewhere.  HH24 distinguishes between 24-hour and 12-hour formats. whatever your data needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the control file you need to also specify the types and format for the date:

```
...
DATE1 DATE "MM/DD/YYYY" NULLIF (DATE1=BLANKS),
DATE2 DATE "MM/DD/YYYY" NULLIF (DATE2=BLANKS),
...
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE SOLUTION ITS MORE CONVENIENT @Gnqz